# How do linux syscalls implementations handle a caught signal?

Tags: signals, system-calls

I understand how signals work in general and I understand that syscalls are changing the task state to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` or `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` to prevent signal interruption on critical sections. 
Now I'm trying to understand what happens when the task state is `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` and a signal is caught during a syscall.

**My questions are the following:**

- How does the syscalls implementation (for example `read()`) handle a signal. For example, in case of `read()`, let's say we are inside a read function in the ext2 filesystem driver. Does the function check every time if a signal had occurred? Because it needs to free the resources it allocated and/or unlock the locks it aquired. To sum up, my question is how the syscall implementation (that includes calling to many different functions in the kernel and in drivers) know that the signal had occurred and free the resources it allocated?
- If the syscall is waiting on a mutex to be available (the task is blocked) and a signal occurs, how does the kernel inform the calling function for the mutex `lock()` that it wasn't locked but a signal had occurred?
- Let's say a signal occurred during the execution of function `read()` of the ext2 driver. How does the VFS layer and the main syscall function (`read()`) know that the ext2 driver read function had failed because of a signal. Do they all have the necessary checks for it? Isn't it a lot of checks to make?

Comment: signals happen only in user-land. In kernel-land they don't exist. Processors have interrupts. Read a [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Answer (score 1):

> How does the syscalls implementation (for example read()) handle a
>   signal.

Well this might be part of the misunderstanding we talk about syscalls a lot as if they're one thing, but in reality there's the userspace interface through typically through a stdlib. And the kernel space part, the one that does the work of the syscall, is a kernel thread running kernel code. Kernel threads don't play by the same rules as userspace threads and signals are queued and potentially coalesced and may not even be delivered.

> ... For example, in case of read(), let's say we are inside a read
>   function in the ext2 filesystem driver. Does the function check every
>   time if a signal had occurred? Because it needs to free the resources
>   it allocated and/or unlock the locks it aquired. To sum up, my
>   question is how the syscall implementation (that includes calling to
>   many different functions in the kernel and in drivers) know that the
>   signal had occurred and free the resources it allocated?

It doesn't need to because the filesystem code will be run as a kernel thread without signals.  There's a high probability that your syscall won't immediately trigger kenrel action anyway, rather queue for a worker thread to complete. In which case the thread would typically process the signal while waiting for the I/O to complete, this is interruptable behavior.  Notice that this happens in userspace outside the context where the syscall is run.  Kernel threads don't respond to syscall partially because what they'd be doing is complex to save and restore in weird contexts.

> If the syscall is waiting on a mutex to be available (the task is
>   blocked) and a signal occurs, how does the kernel inform the calling
>   function for the mutex lock() that it wasn't locked but a signal had
>   occurred?

This shouldn't happen in kernel space with signals queued. It's important to protect userspace code from unsafe situation with signals, so that'd be up to the application write to figure out if it was an issue and how to fix it.

> Let's say a signal occurred during the execution of function read() of
>   the ext2 driver. How does the VFS layer and the main syscall function
>   (read()) know that the ext2 driver read function had failed because of
>   a signal. Do they all have the necessary checks for it? Isn't it a lot
>   of checks to make?

It doesn't because it won't fail as kernel processes don't act on signals. It will be queued until control is returned to the userspace process that was signaled.

See also:

[How signals are handled in kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355280/how-signals-are-handled-in-kernel)

Which is this may be a dupe of.