Hit a strange signal settings of a kernel thread in Linux
I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), and using busybox as init.
Now I hit a strange problem about signal settings of a kernel thread in system.
The kernel thread is from a device driver, and by cat /proc/pid/status, I found its signal settings are as follows,
SigQ:   0/31126
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000004000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: ffffffffffffbfff
SigCgt: 0000000000004000

Other kernel threads have 0xffffffffffffffff of SigIgn.
The kernel thread is started with kthread_run() as other threads do.
The setting of SigCgt and ShdPnd make the kernel thread unable to go into waiting status, instead, the kernel thread now is in a busy-loop on down_interruptible.
So I am wondering is it correct about the kernel thread's signal settings? Where are the signal settings configured for kernel thread, is it possible for me to customize this settings, if so, how to??

How signals are handled in kernel says Linux's kernel threads (i.e. threads of the kernel, listed with no corresponding executable in process lists) can't receive signals at all. More precisely, any signal delivered to a kernel thread is ignored.. Does that answer your question?

I read the signal handling of kernel thread a little, and I thought the kernel thread should NOT take any signal, but to my surprise, the setting of bit15 (SIGTERM?) is clear in the kernel thread's SigIgn, why it is cleared, and how to set it? The setting of bit15 in ShnPnd and SigCgt make the kernel thread unable to go to waiting state, and it is looping in down_interruptible returned with -EINTR.

I am not quite familiar with the kernel api about signal handling. But I can try add some checking of signal in the kernel thread.

After code reading and testing, I think I figure it out.
First, as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355519/535730
mentioned, kernel thread will ignore its signals, but I think it does NOT mean the kernel thread cannot get the signal.
Linux kernel thread can use allow_signal(signr) to enable the receiption of the signal, and do what it want with the signal, such as exiting its execution.
So, in my case, the kernel driver enables the reception of SIGTERM, and would stop its execution. The problem is it did NOT stop itself in a simple way, it needs the vendor to refactor its stopping logics.
